# Qual o comando semelhante no git ao "git revert" do IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij

Como reverter o estado de um **arquivo específico** através de comandos git? Semelhante a opção `git revert` do IntelliJ onde eu seleciono os arquivos que quero reverter. Quando seleciono todas as opções no terminal do `git revert`, me lista todas as branches.

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Development/git/oknok-clicktag$ git revert 
Display all 217 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Comment: So' para esclarecer, queres reverter o estado de um ficheiro para um commit anterior especifico? Ou simplesmente desfazer as alteracoes efectuadas desde o ultimo commit?

Comment: Desfazer as alterações feitas num arquivo especifico comparada ao último commit. (Não foi "comitada" essas alterações)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para desfazer as alteracoes de um ficheiro especifico desde o ultimo commit (aka *discard changes*), basta fazer

```
git checkout -- path/to/file
```

Para reverter todos os ficheiros

```
git checkout -- .
```

Ver seccao "Examples" de [Git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Cara, como alguém que começou no Mercurial, toda vez que tenho que usar `checkout` para desfazer alterações lembro do [Steve Losh](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2013/04/git-koans/#one-thing-well).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Lol gostei do link ;)